# Auto open file input on IE

Tags: file, internet-explorer, upload

Is it possible to auto open the file input on IE?

If you do

```
$(input).click();
```

IE doesn't submit the form. Maybe i can get its value somehow?

```
$(input).val()
```

Doesnt work, this will give you fakepath.

Any Idea about this? Cloning does also not work. Another possibility woudl be, to place the open button somwhere else on the page, without the input box for the path.

Is anything like this possible somehow? I have some img's and if you click on these images a file browser should pop up. Maybe theres some plugin i could use? Anything?

Trying out stuff for hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the path for security purposes .. but you can use a workaround solution to hide the traditional input element behind your custom design , like the following example http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: I know but it isn't about styling. The user doesn't see the form anyway. I just want to auto open the input of a hidden form, for a nice user experience. But seems like there's really no hack anymore. :(

Answer (score 1):

Call `$(input).focus().click();`

Tested in Firefox 10 and IE9.

Comment: Won't work. If you do a click on an input, you can't submit it anymore. Just try it and you'll see.